# Can the performance in these scenarios be effectively improved by customizing Timsort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, timsort

Some of the characteristic features of the data sets I am working with are showing the following trends:-

1. First 50-70% of the array is almost sorted with the last 30% completely scrambled.

   - Will it be effective if I replace the insertion sort part with shell sort?
2. First 50-70% of the array is almost sorted with the last 30% containing a lot of
   turtles.

   - Does the occurrence of turtles matter so much that I should ditch Timsort in favor of
     this Comb sort variation - 
     [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort#Combsort_with_different_end).
     Their best case performances show O(n) but avg case performance is better for Tim
     sort with O(n log n), whereas Comb sort has Ω (n log n) but does this take the
     modified version of Comb sort or density of turtles into account?
3. Same as 2nd scenario, but partially sorted output is fine if it can improve performance.
   For example, an array containing 1,000,000 elements can have its smallest 1% (i.e. 
   10,000 elements) in the first 1% slots of the array but need not be sorted internally.

   - Can this be done by pulling out after a certain recursion depth in Quick sort to 
     place the elements approximately near their deserved place.

If it is relevant, here is the Timsort code for Java that I am trying to modify - [code](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/main/java/util/TimSort.java?view=co).

Comment: Is this really a worthwhile thing to try to optimize?  Have you profiled it?

Comment: My mentor is working on a paper for his doctorate which is based on Data Mining and he is primarily working on this algorithm which can draw heuristics for Match Fixing in Cricket. So, even if replacing insertion sort with shell sort might not make a huge difference, I have to explore criteria 2 & 3 as he has assured me that the databases are going to be quite big - and any optimizations will be appreciated to reduce run-time of some features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best answer is that it is not possible to *reliably predict* whether customizing TimSort will produce worthwhile performance improvements for your datasets.  You will just need to try it and see.

And I'm going to repeat my advice from my comment: profile it first!

Until you have profiled the application running on representative data, you cannot know if there is even a chance that this will help.  For instance, if the computation is only spending 5% of its time sorting data, then a 50% speedup of the sort algorithm will only result in a 2.5% speedup of the application.  And that is simply not worth wasting your time on.